# Schengen D Visa for 1 month visit

Tags: visas, schengen, study

I am ineligible to enter the Schengen area right now since I've exhausted my 90/180 days. However, there is an month long internship offer in Europe that I am keen to take up. Is there any possibility of getting a D class visa for a 1 month visit? (I assume the host institution will be willing to help me get one. They do this regularly for other students who stay longer).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Correcting myself. The previous answer was not correct.

Here's the [Italian official website](http://www.esteri.it/mae/en/ministero/servizi/stranieri/ingressosoggiornoinitalia/visto_ingresso/tipologie_visto_durata.html):

> Long sojourn or "national" Visas (NV), which are only valid for visits that are longer than 90 days (type D),

That's quite clear.

Comment: The problem is D visa is issued for 3 months or more when you apply a residence permit application. You should apply for another fresh C visa. Please check.

Comment: There is no such thing called Schengen D visa as D visas are national visas for long term residency over 3 months. It is not clear from OP questions where he is studying. Here is the link: http://ec.europa.eu/immigration/do-i-need-a-visa/do-i-need-a-long-stay-visa_en

Comment: @chx please read http://meta.travel.stackexchange.com/questions/3097/if-a-question-is-worth-answering-its-probably-worth-upvoting

Comment: @pbu: Getting another C visa will not help the asker -- the 180/90 day rule applies _per person_, not per visa, per passport, or per trip.

Comment: Rewritten the answer based on the Italian Ministry of Foreign Affairs website.